# Quelle est la différence entre val et vallée?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, géographie

Bien, selon [ceci](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/val), val = valley en anglais. Pour moi, vallée = valley (voir [ici](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/vall%C3%A9e)).

Alors, ma question est: Quelles circonstances distinguent 
le mot "val" du mot "vallée"?
S'agit-il de la différence entre noms propres et noms (normaux/simples)?

Mais regardez dans la première référence

> La bonne image environnementale du val de Loire...

et dans la deuxième

> Il est vrai que, dans toute la vallée du Saint-Laurent...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mon explication va s'inspirer de celle donnée par Henri Adamczewski dans *Le Français déchiffré Clé du langage et des langues* (pages 222,224,225) au sujet de : an/année,  jour/journée,   soir/soirée,    matin/matinée.

Pour moi, *val* sert à **présenter** un lieu précis (le Val D'Escrein) ou une forme géomorphologique (un val perché, par monts et par vaux).

*Vallon*, *vallée* **évoquent** un val pour en parler, apporter un commentaire. Exemple :

> La vallée s'étirait sur plusieurs kilomètres.

C'est probablement pour cela que c'est le mot *vallée* et non *val* qui est utilisé métaphoriquement dans la phrase suivante de Pougens trouvée dans le littré:

> Ce qui fait et fera toujours de ce monde une vallée de larmes, c'est l'insatiable cupidité et l'indomptable orgueil des hommes.

Answer (score 2):

**Il n'y a pas de différence au point de vue du sens courant.**

Les deux mots sont des dérivés du latin *vallis*.

L'instinct me dit que vallée est dérivé de val au travers d'une féminisation de la Renaissance. Mais *valle* (prononcé vallé) est une forme déclinée de *vallis*. L'inverse est donc possible.

**Dans l'usage**, le mot à utiliser en toute rigueur géographie, géologie ou hydrographie est vallée. Ce qui explique que val soit choisi par les offices de tourisme etc (cf [la page Wikipedia de vallée](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vall%C3%A9e)) pour dénommer une région, et aussi que le mot ait pris un sens plus poétique.

Comment: D'ailleurs la page Wikipédia du Val de Loire commence par ces mots : *Le **Val** de Loire est une région naturelle française correspondant à la partie de la **vallée** de la Loire située, d'amont en aval, dans les départements du Loiret, de Loir-et-Cher, d'Indre-et-Loire et de Maine-et-Loire*.
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Val_de_Loire

Answer (score 2):

[val = petite vallée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/val)

val est peu utilisé, sauf dans des noms de région (*Val de Marne*), ou dans des expressions : *par monts et par vaux*